# php array goes vertical instead of horizontal after styling

Tags: php, css

I have an array of letters. After I added the styling, the array went from horizontal to vertical.

here is the code:

```
$alphabetical_array = range('a','z');
function AddLinks($letter)
{
$title = strtoupper($letter);
$a = "<a href='alpha_search.php?letter=".$letter."' class='alphabtn'><font color='#FFFFFF'>".$title."</font></a>";
return($a);
}

$format_array = array_map("AddLinks", $alphabetical_array);
echo implode($format_array);
```

here is the css:

```
.alphabtn {
    max-width:10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px ;
    text-align:left;
    clear: both; 
    text-indent:0;
    display: block;
    font: bold 12px/14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #391b61;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #864fd3 0%, #553285 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#864fd3), color-stop(100%,#553285));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #864fd3 0%,#553285 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #864fd3 0%,#553285 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #864fd3 0%,#553285 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #864fd3 0%,#553285 100%);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#864fd3, #553285);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px 1px #a55aff;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px 1px #a55aff;
    behavior: url(../login/_ui/js/PIE.htc);
}.alphabtn:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #553285), color-stop(1, #864fd3) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #553285 5%, #864fd3 100% );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #553285 0%, #864fd3 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#553285', endColorstr='#864fd3');
    background-color:#553285;
}.alphabtn:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

Comment: Font tag?  People still use those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have

```
clear: both;
```

set on your tag. pretty sure this will cause the

`<a>`

to be treated as block and break to a new line.

Try removing it.

Comment: also remove display: block;

Comment: your suggesstion did give me an idea, so i removed the display:block and that did the trick. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You have `display: block;` in the css. That will cause each element to display on its own line. Remove it and everything else should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.alphabtn {
    max-width:10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px ;
    text-align:left;
    clear: both; 
    text-indent:0;
    display: block;
```

to

```
.alphabtn {
    max-width:10px; //Why this line?
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px ;
    text-align:left;
    text-indent:0;
    display: inline-block; (or delete the row)
```